# how do i declare a string with arguments parsed from commandline?

Tags: c#

how do i declare a string with arguments inside?

suppose

```
string path = "C:\\Work\\6.70_Extensions\\"
```

and `6.70_Extensions` is replaced by args parsed
i tried this:

```
string path = ("C:\\Work\\{0}\\NightlyBuild\\", args[0]) ;
```

where args[0] is a string. I suppose my syntax is wrong somewhere

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be using `string.Format` for that.

```
string path = string.Format("C:\\Work\\{0}\\NightlyBuild\\", args[0]) ;
```

Comment: As a side note you can use: 
`string path = string.Format(@"C:\Work\{0}\NightlyBuild\", args[0]);` 
to avoid the escape characters.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx):

```
string path = String.Format("C:\\Work\\{0}\\NightlyBuild\\", args[0]);
```

or simple concatenation (after a null check, of cource):

```
string path = "C:\\Work\\" + args[0] + "\\NightlyBuild\\";
```